# On Off Switch - Checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

In the following code - how can I perform check and uncheck. Right now it is only doing one thing:

```
    $('#div_group').click(function() {
        var status = $(this).attr('checked');
        if( ! status) {
        status = false;
        }
        $("input[id~='div_group']").attr('checked', true);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.prop` instead of `.attr`:

```
$('#div_group').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $("input[id~='div_group']").prop('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
});
```

Why? http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 3):

You need to use prop instead of attr.
Try...

```
$("input[id~='div_group']").prop('checked', true);
```

and then to uncheck it set the `true` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) in this case to see the `:checked` property of the element. After doing so, you should use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the `:checked` property of the element to either ***true*** or ***false*** respectively.

```
$('#div_group').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $("input[id~='div_group']").prop('checked', false);
    } else {
         $("input[id~='div_group']").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```